# calculate sum of values of a specific attribute in a table in rethinkDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have the following dataset in my rethinkdb Database. I want to calculate the sum of one attribute named **Min**. I want to sum the all values of 
**Min**.

For example with the following dataset the query should return **8**

```
{
 "completedAt": Fri Dec 30 2016 10:05:17 GMT+00:00 ,
  "Min": 0 ,
}
{
 "completedAt": Fri Dec 30 2016 10:05:17 GMT+00:00 ,
  "Min": 3 ,
}
{
 "completedAt": Fri Dec 30 2016 10:05:17 GMT+00:00 ,
  "Min": 5 ,
}
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sum:

```
r.db('dbone').table("usertable").sum("Min")
```

You got error:

> Expected type NUMBER but found OBJECT

with `r.db('dbone').table("usertable").filter(r.row("userid").eq("‌​002") ).pluck('Min').sum()` cause after `pluck` you get array of objects. To make `sum` on result of `pluck` you should get field like this:

```
r.db('dbone').table("usertable").filter(r.row("userid").eq("‌​002") ).pluck('Min')("Min").sum()
```

or pass field name to `sum`:

```
r.db('dbone').table("usertable").filter(r.row("userid").eq("‌​002") ).pluck('Min').sum("Min")
```

Comment: Thanks   it worked like a  charm  .  I didnt  thought this way

Comment: well  can  you tell me how the sum can  be applied  if  am  using a  map function   like  this       Bal: r.row('left')('Min').sum('Min')

Comment: well i can find  the soultion for   the summing up the  values in a mapping function
Bal: r.row('left')('Min').sum('Min')  .  

how it works in a mapping function

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use a sum command on the dataset? Probably something like this -

```
r.table("tablename").sum("Min").run(conn, callback)
```

I'm not familiar with rethinkDB, but I had a look at its APIs and you can find more on the sum command [here](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/sum/).

Comment: well  am  getting this for  particular UserID  ,  and  there are  many  datasets against eachUserId  so when i  run  the following query 

**r.db('dbone').table("usertable").filter(r.row("userid").eq("002")
  ).pluck('Min').sum()**   it says    Expected type NUMBER but found OBJECT

Comment: Is `userid` here a string or integer? if its an integer you might have to remove the double quotes there.

Comment: well  in reql  we  use  double quotes  the  query  runs fine  when i dont use  sum()